# What happens when a dryad tree awakens?

Tags: magic, creature-design, mythical-creatures

A dryad is a fey-like creature bound to a tree. Always female and mostly human-shaped with some tree-like features, her life-force is bound to her tree - should the tree die then so does the dryad and vice versa. Illness and injury are also shared. Dryads take it upon themselves to be protectors of the forest, especially their own tree and the area around it. Bringing axes to their forest is bound to give you their ire, and fire their hatred. Being allowed close to a dryad's tree is a sign of great honour. Their powers vary, but often include supernatural resilience due to bark-like skin and being somewhat spirit-like, talking to trees and other plants, knowing much of what happens in their forest and fast travel within it. While they focus on the trees, they also care for other plants and creatures in the forest. A dryad cannot venture too far or too long from her home tree without falling weak and eventually dying.

An old tree in an old forest can sometimes awaken, gaining a mind of its own and dragging up its roots to gain mobility and a somewhat humanoid form while still looking mostly like a tree. Such a creature is often called an ent or treant, or sometimes an awakened tree or walking tree. Any tree could awaken by itself, but a tree with the potential for it can be nudged into awakening by a druid or another ent. Just as trees do not have single genders the way humans do, an ent can be male, female, both or neither, though male ents are the most common. Ents take it upon themselves to guard their whole forest, or even other forests when necessary, because of the kinship they feel with the trees they came from. They are big, slow and strong, and can live very long lives - much longer than its tree would have. An ent can survive without its forest for it is sustained by its own magic and sunlight, though the ent would usually not want to leave without good reason. Their powers, besides their great strength, are usually some simple communication with the trees in their forests and sometimes "tree-herding": making normal trees move around a bit, to go to other places or hinder foes.

My question is this: what if the bonded tree of a dryad awakens into a treant? Feel free to nudge the details of what I've written if it would make a better answer.

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been closed for being too opinion based. The biggest problem I see is you haven't defined how the relationship between an ent and dryad works. Since this is your creation you have the freedom to decide. Maybe a tree with a dryad can't become an ent and thats the end of the argument. Maybe the dryad fuses with the tree to become the ent, or maybe they become a team and work together and extend each others abilities. You could even make ents male and dryads all female for relationships. You have to remember these are your creations and rules and you choose what happens.

Comment: This actually came up in a recent DnD session I DM'd, and I wasn't sure how to resolve it. I thought about posting to RPG.se, but want here because I'm more interested in creativity than strict interpretation of a ruleset. DnD does not specify the relationship between dryads and ents, that's partly why I'm asking.

Comment: This appears to be asking for a discussion or perhaps it is a solicitation for commentary about your idea.  That's off-topic (at all SE sites).  Do you have a specific question we can answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You have the makings for an awesome pair of characters.**

There are so many things you could do with these two!  The pair could carry the story by themselves.

1:  The tree used to be like a baby.  Now it is sentient, with a mind of its own.  It loves the dryad, who cared for it and guarded it when it was just a tree.  But now, like a teenager with growing independence, it chafes when she treats it the way she always has.

2:  The dryad is very powerful.  The check on her power is her confinement to the locale of the tree.  If the tree becomes mobile, what does that mean for the dryad?  Does she want to expand her sphere of influence?  Or does the thought of the wider world produce crippling anxiety?

3:  The dryad is concerned for her tree.  She may not care much for the forest as a whole or other trees.  But the tree might care about these thing.  It might try to gently persuade her to take a larger view.  This would be a good match for the "crippling anxiety" dryad in #2.  Over the course of the story the ent may learn to be careful what it wishes for, as the dryad loses her anxiety and flexes her muscle.  She has had no reason to learn subtlety or restraint.

4:  The dryad loves her tree.  Is she its lover?  Can the ent and dryad merge temporarily and form a being greater than the sum of its parts?

I hope you have the writing chops!  You have invented an excellent duo from whom I can imagine loads of storylines and narrative energy.

Answer (score 3):

A dryad bonded tree is already "awakened," through the dryad.

It's a different sort of awakening than is seen with an ent, but it likely prevents a tree from having that particular type of awakening.

I do have some questions though--
How is a dryad born? How much time is there between birth and the bonding with the tree? Is it a regular tree beforehand? Is she born from the tree?

These questions really shape the answer to yours. If a baby dryad runs about bonded to a sapling or the tree is bonded to them from the moment it is planted, then there's already a consciousness sort of present, and there might not be any room for an ent consciousness.

If an dryad can tell that a tree has the potential to be an ent, they might not bond with it (or an elder dryad might not decide to bond them to it, however it works or whoever makes the decision.) OR it could be the opposite--you can only ever bond with a tree that had the potential to be an Ent because of the way the tree has to connect to dryad consciousness, but the process destroys the possibility of being ent.

If it's the first one--that they don't generally pick trees that might be ents--it might mean that a mistake was made in this case. That it isn't something that is supposed to happen.

I would say that if it did happen (unless it happens as a natural part of things in your world, in which case consider the process of both "awakenings" and bonding...) it's something that is very very rare indeed.

Of course you know what the advantages are, which is why you are asking the question. You want a dryad that can move beyond the bounds of the forest, which she would be able to do if her tree was mobile and can go with her.

As to what it would be like once it did happen, it's a magical world and you can make it work any way you like...anything could be true.

Here's what we know--
They would be connected emotionally and physically. They might have a telepathic bond. Injury shared or echoed between them. Might work differently if you want it to.

The downside--the dryad is only meant to be connected to a simple tree, not a full sentient consciousness. It might mean she can never fully unfold her consciousness within the tree (which might be the way dryads reproduce for all we know). It might be driving both of them slowly mad.

Actually, an ent might even be born from the melding of a dryad with her tree, not your way--a dryad melds with her tree completely, dying, and either an ent or another dryad (or both or a whole bunch of kids at once) are born, through one of the other trees in the forest. If this process is used maybe something went wrong...